# Cambiar la Transperencia de un Prefab en Unity

Tags: unity3d

Tengo tres cubos (uno delante de otro) en una escena de Unity y me gustaría que, cuando se diera una condición, el primer cubo saliera semi-transparente para que se pudiera ver el de detrás.

He probado con lo siguiente:

```
cubo1.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color.a = 0.5f;
```

Pero me da error. Tengo los cubos declarados de la siguiente forma:

```
public GameObject cubo1;
```

He cambiado el Shader del Material de `Standard` a `Legacy Shaders/Transparent/Diffuse` por el tema del canal Alpha, pero nada...

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea?

Comment: Mira la pagina http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ para temas relacionados con los videojuegos

Comment: @lois6b [gamedev.SE] no sólo está en inglés, sino que no se especializa en código. La pregunta está totalmente relacionada a este sitio, e incluso podrás ver algunas de las otras preguntas de Unity: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity

Comment: Vale, está en ingles pero lo que dices de "no se especializa en codigo" .. no creo que sea cierto.

Answer (score 6):

Para quien le interese, ya lo he resuelto. Aquí la solución:

```
public GameObject cubo;

public void Transparente() //assignado a un button
{
    cubo.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 0.3f); //llamo al canal alpha en el último valor (1=100%, 0.5f = 50%, 0 = 0%)
}

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    Material matTrans = new Material(Shader.Find("Transparent/Diffuse"));
    GetComponent<Renderer>().material = matTrans; //Crear nuevo material Transparente
}
```

Espero que ayude si alguien lo necesita!

Answer (score 1):

La estructura Color a la que estás accediendo en

```
cubo1.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color.a = 0.5f;
```

es una copia de la que hay en el material. De forma que acceder sólo a la propiedad "a" involucraría cambiar el alpha de la copia, y por ésto te da error (sucede algo parecido cuando intentas hacer transform.position.x = 5)

La forma correcta de modificar el valor en C# es como lo has hecho en tu respuesta, con el problema de que puedes sobreescribir o perder los otros valores de color, o haciendo algo como esto:

```
Color c = cubo1.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color;
c.a = 0.5F;
cubo1.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = c;
```

De esta forma dejas los valores anteriores r,g,b intactos, no como en tu ejemplo.

Además de eso, para que puedas ver los efectos del cambio de alpha, efectivamente el material debe ser de tipo "Transparent" o "Cutout", como ya te han comentado.

Espero que te sirva ^^

Answer (score 0):

También puedes modificar el material, Arriba ves que dice *`transparent`*.

Mira este ejemplo:

[image: Ejemplo en el inspector]